# Expand a specific command line argument

Tags: bash

If we have a function that can take an arbitrary number of arguments, we can access any of them at will in their expanded form with '$n', of course. We can retrieve arguments exactly as typed on the CL into an array with:

```
arguments=(`history 1`)
```

Now, is it possible to pick some argument out of 'arguments' and ask bash to expand that single argument?

Answer (score 1):

You mean like `"${arguments[2]}"` to get the third item in the array?

Comment: Sure, that grabs one of the unexpanded arguments. Now, how can we ask bash to expand just that one argument, just as it would be expanded if we examined '$@'. In other words, how can we expand _just_ one argument of our choosing?

Comment: @rayandrews: You mean process the glob, if any? You could pass is through `eval` or you could just take the e.g. `$3` parameter directly since you know it was already expanded.

Comment: Sorpigal, that won't work. Say my typed arguments are " * $VARIABLE ".  Now say I want to expand $VARIABLE. It is the 2nd argument as far as 'history 1' goes, but what number is it as far as $@ goes? See what I mean? I have to grab it from 'history 1' and *then* expand it since '*' could  expand to any number which makes it near impossible for me to search out the expansion for $VARIABLE -- how would I find it?

Comment: @rayandrews: It's worse than that. Even if you find it, how do you know `$VARIABLE` is even in scope inside your script? There's only so far you can take this and at some point you're going to have to settle for approximately correct (or correct most-of-the-time).

Comment: well that's correct, but at least it's a seperate problem.  Anyway I just thought that bash might give us some way to expand CLI arguments 'one at a time' so to speak. It should be doable in theory, we'd just need some access to the code that does the expansions.  Bash is sure frustrating, so many little frustrations.

Comment: @rayandrews: You'd have to hack bash itself to expose some mechanism.